# Retrieve images embedded in Excel file

Tags: sql, image, excel, vba

I'm currently in the process of upscaling an Excel solution to a web solution. In this process, I need to upload the existing data into the new (SQL Server) database.

Problem is, that I also need to upload the images that are stored in the Excel file (as shapes). In the database, they will be stored as bytearray in PNG format.

What is the best way to retrieve the source of any embedded image?

I'm currently thinking of either using `ws.Shapes("img_1").CopyPicture` and some API functions to retrieve it - but so far, got stuck in figuring out the proper API functions. Also, not sure if there isn't an easier/more elegant way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally found a solution. Not sure this is the most elegant version - and right now it requires IrfanView or another converter - but it does the job. Can be called with `fctStrConvertImageToString(Sheets("YourSheet").Shapes("YorImage"))` and will return the PBG of this image as string:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(8) As Byte
End Type

Private Type PICTDESC
    cbSize As Long
    picType As Long
    hImage As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function OpenClipboard& Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd&)
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard& Lib "user32" ()
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData& Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat%)
Private Declare Function SetClipboardData& Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat&, ByVal hMem&)
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard& Lib "user32" ()
Private Declare Function CopyImage& Lib "user32" (ByVal handle&, ByVal un1&, ByVal n1&, ByVal n2&, ByVal un2&)
Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" (ByVal lpsz As String, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32" (pPictDesc As PICTDESC, ByRef riid As GUID, ByVal fOwn As Long, ByRef ppvObj As IPicture) As Long

Public Function fctStrConvertImageToString(shp As Shape) As String
    Const cStrPath As String = "C:\Temp\"
    Const cStrFileName As String = "temp"
    Const cStrSourceExtension As String = "bmp"
    Const cStrTargetExtension As String = "png"

    Dim strSource As String, strTarget As String


    If shp.Type <> msoPicture Then Exit Function

    shp.CopyPicture 1, xlBitmap

    strSource = cStrPath & cStrFileName & "." & cStrSourceExtension
    strTarget = cStrPath & cStrFileName & "." & cStrTargetExtension

    subSavePicAsBitmap strSource

    subConvertFile strSource, strTarget

    fctStrConvertImageToString = fctStrReadFile(strTarget)

    Kill strSource
    Kill strTarget
End Function

Private Sub subSavePicAsBitmap(strFile As String)
    Const cStrPictureIID = "{7BF80981-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB}"

    Dim hCopy&: OpenClipboard 0&
    Dim iPic As IPicture
    Dim tIID As GUID
    Dim tPICTDEST As PICTDESC
    Dim lngReturn As Long

    hCopy = CopyImage(GetClipboardData(2), 0, 0, 0, &H4)
    CloseClipboard
    If hCopy = 0 Then Exit Sub

    lngReturn = IIDFromString(StrConv(cStrPictureIID, vbUnicode), tIID)
    If lngReturn Then Exit Sub

    With tPICTDEST
        .cbSize = Len(tPICTDEST)
        .picType = 1
        .hImage = hCopy
    End With
    lngReturn = OleCreatePictureIndirect(tPICTDEST, tIID, 1, iPic)

    SavePicture iPic, strFile
End Sub

Private Sub subConvertFile(strSource As String, strTarget As String)
    Const cStrConverter = """c:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe"""
    Shell cStrConverter & " " & strSource & " /convert=" & strTarget, 0
End Sub

Private Function fctStrReadFile(strFile As String)
    Dim hFile As Long

    hFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Binary Access Read As #hFile
    fctStrReadFile = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
    Close #hFile

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind getting all images as files in your disk and afterwards uploading those to your database, you could just save the Excel workbook or worksheet as "Web Page".

That will create a html file and a directory filled with whatever images (one PNG file per image) the original Excel file has.